# SVG with USE tag not rendering

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg

The DOM already includes an empty SVG tag (`svg`). When I try to dynamically append a `USE` tag of an existing SVG symbol (`symbol`) with an id (`iconId`):

```
svg.empty();
svg[0].setAttribute('viewBox', symbol.getAttribute('viewBox'));
svg.append('<use xlink:href="#' + iconId + '"></use>');
```

it no longer renders the SVG. In Chrome, it renders if I add:

```
 element.html(element.html());
```

or manually manipulate the `viewBox` attribute, but that's not a real solution and IE doesn't like it at all.
It's worth mentioning that if I append SVG graphics directly, the element renders.

What is happening here and why isn't the SVG drawing after appending the USE tag?

Comment: i can only guess but: could it be the use tag is rendered before the svg is loaded? (not before it is included, but actually loaded)

Comment: Pesumably append sticks the data in the html namespace rather than the SVG namespace.

Comment: @DoXicK - No, SVG and symbol are both hardcoded in the page. Script runs after DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: @RobertLongson - Can you give a solution for that? I've tried innerHTML as well.

Comment: "The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, **without waiting for stylesheets, images,**" which means it could be possible the svg is NOT loaded yet. It might be requested but not downloaded yet. Unless you inlined it of course.

Comment: use DOMParser and make sure your content root node has an explicit namespace (xmlns) attribute.

Comment: @DoXicK - Inlined. I don't think it's a matter of a missing content.

Comment: @RobertLongson - I don't want to create a wrapping SVG, only append the USE inside an existing SVG tag. I have declared the proper namespaces on the root html node (and even on the SVG tag itslef)

Comment: If you use DOMParser the use element string will still need a namespace attribute, regardless of the svg root node already having one.

Comment: Don't try to use vanilla jQuery to manipulate SVGs.  It generally doesn't work.  You run into problems with namespaces as Robert said.  Use DOMParser, or create the elements yourself with createElementNS(), or use one of the SVG JS libraries like jQuery SVG, SVG.js, Raphael etc).

Comment: @ChenEshchar reason to think it's about missing content is that it works after a repaint... but yeah, if it's inlined it shouldnt be a problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After all it was indeed a matter of namespaces.

Specifically, SVG elements and attributes must be created and set using `document.createElementNS` and `node.setAttributeNS`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(evt) { 
  var svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
      xlinkns = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
      use = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'use');
  
  use.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, 'xlink:href', '#save');
  document.getElementById('useSVG').appendChild(use);
});
```

```css
#svgStore { 
  display: none;  
}

#useSVG {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg style="display:none;" id="svgStore" style="display: none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="save"><title>save</title>       <g id="svgstore3748a955346b4a088bbdc55a22f56504_x31_6_13_"> 
        <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;" d="M9,4h2V2H9V4z M13,13H3v1h10V13z M13,11H3v1h10V11z M13,0H0v16h16V3L13,0z
   M3,1h9v4H3V1z M14,15H2V8h12V15z M13,9H3v1h10V9z">
     
   </path> 
      </g> 
    </symbol>
</svg>
SVG use:
<svg id="useSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

Thanks to @RobertLongson and http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/basics/shapes/js_dom/ for directing to the answer.